# Path connected without bounded path connected subset?

Tags: gn.general-topology, path-connected

**Question:** Is there a path connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$, without any bounded path connected subset (aside from singletons)?

**Motivation:** If we replace "path connected" by "connected", then the answer is positive. It was proven by Stefan Mazurkiewicz, see [the original article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm2/fm2112.pdf).

Comment: this may be of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36587/a-question-about-unbounded-connected-subsets-of-the-plane

Comment: i think the answer works for path connectedness as well, although this is not what you ask

Comment: If the set $E$ is path connected, then it contains a path (barring trivialities), and that path is itself a bounded path connected subset of $E$.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Or a single point is a path connected subset of any set.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: Does every path connected subset of the plane have a non-degenerate bounded connected subset which is *not* path connected?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: The set $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$, i.e. the $x$-axis, certainly doesn't.  Any set with nonempty interior certainly does, because you can put a tiny copy of the topologist's sine curve in there.

Comment: Let $E$ be a path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not a singleton, and let $x,y \in E$ be distinct points. Then there is a path from $x$ to $y$ in $E$, i.e. there is a continuous function $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow E$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$. The unit interval $[0,1]$ is compact and connected, hence its image $\gamma([0,1])$ under the continuous function $\gamma$ must also be compact (hence bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$) and connected. The subset $\gamma([0,1])\subseteq E$ is your desired bounded path-connected subset of $E$, which is not a singleton since $x\neq y$.